# Identify the non-zero element in a list which is close to given number in Python

Tags: python

I have list like this:

```
lst = [1, 5, 0, 0, 4, 0]
```

EDIT:
I would like find the location of the first number in list that is not equal to zero and it is **closest** given number.

```
a = 3  # (given number)
```

It should return 4 as index and value too.
I tried with this:

```
min(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-a))
```

but its shows the 0 element too.

which is the better way for doing this?

Comment: Please define "close"!

Comment: @KlausD. going by the code I think he means "closest"

Comment: Well, it will have to be defined, for us to understand the question and most importantly in code.

Comment: Ok, the question was updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, just filter out the zeros after enumerating:

```
In [1]: lst = [1, 5, 0, 0, 4, 0]

In [2]: a = 3

In [3]: min(filter(lambda x: x[1] != 0, enumerate(lst)),
            key=lambda x: abs(x[1] - a))
Out[3]: (4, 4)
```

Your own example does return `(4, 4)` too for the given values though. With `a = 0` there's a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is pretty close. You just need to replace zero with infinity.

```
min(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: abs(a - (x[1] if x[1] else float("inf"))))
```

Edit: flipped `a` and `x[1]`